# Differentiating functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to differentiate
$f(t) = t\sqrt[4]{t}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{t}}$
$y = \frac{x^{2}-5 x+4}{x^{2}}$
$y= x^{4/3}-8x^{2/3}$

Using the derivative rules, I got
$f'(t)=\frac{-1}{4}t^{\frac{-3}{4}}$
along with
$y'=x+\frac{1}{2}$
 and $y'=\frac {4}{3}x^{1/3} - \frac {16}{3}x^{-1/3}$
And those are totally wrong, so can someone tell me the right answers so I could try to see what I did wrong in my procedure?

Comment: I would use wolfram for this kind of thing.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ \frac{df}{dt} = \frac{5}{4}t^{1/4} + \frac{1}{4} t^{-5/4}$

$ \frac{dy}{dx} = -8 x^{-3} + 5 x^{-2}$

$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{4}{3} x^{1/3} - \frac{16}{3} x^{-1/3}$